# Java: Async MongoTemplate / MongoOperation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is there a way to insert something asynchronously into mongodb?

I know that mongodb is fairly quick in most cases, but thought maybe I can save some milliseconds by returning as soon as the command is given.

It is for those use cases where you connect to the server to send mongodb a command to insert something. You want to return back to the client once the command is issued and not necessarily wait for a response from mongodb.

I read the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/

It only seems to read asynchronously, not insert asychronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Spring Data MongoDB documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async) only shows example of using the `@Async` annotation on query methods, but it is possible to use it on every method.

Quoting this documentation:

> Repository queries can be executed asynchronously using Spring’s asynchronous method execution capability. This means the method will return immediately upon invocation and the actual query execution will occur in a task that has been submitted to a Spring TaskExecutor.

Asynchronous invocation of methods is not a Spring Data concern but a Spring Core concern so you can refer to [Spring framework documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-async).

Simply said, you just need to add the `@Async` annotation on the method you want and configure a proper task executor in Spring configuration. A sample XML configuration would be:

```xml
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" />
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
```

Comment: if I'm using spring boot, would this xml configuration be done automatically if I just use the @Async annotation over my method call? Also I see that Async appears to be valid for custom methods only and not the java driver for mongo which creates the mongotemplate object. Thanks for your answer by the way, it is very detailed.

Comment: @Simon Yes you need this configuration. However if you are using Java config, all you need is the `@EnableAsync` annotation on your configuration class. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/).

Comment: OK thanks - let me test this out and will get back to you.